# Tracking download count of iphone application from AdWords

Tags: iphone, google-ads-api

I have developed a native application for iphone in xcode.
Is there any way of tracking download count of my iphone application via AdWords?
A workmate gave this code to put in my iphone application. But i haven't understood where to put it.

```
    <!-- Google Code for iPhone Ap Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1026052817;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "bgmcCI3K5QIQ0aWh6QM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""  src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1026052817/? label=bgmcCI3K5QIQ0aWh6QM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Why do you want to track the download count through AdWords? Why not just use the download count that Apple give you every day?

Comment: @NickBull i have been providing apple's statistics daily as you say. Unfortunately this is customer idea. And i have to prove that it is possible or impossible via adwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The only people who know if an app is downloaded are the person who downloads it and Apple. The AppStore is the only place to download an app from and so there is no way for you to add any kind of device to measure those metrics.